# how to extract maximum date from web page in dot net window application

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

In my application I want to extract the latest date shown in web page. I am using *System.Xml.Linq.XDocument* class to extract content. But I am not able to extract pubdate of feed. Here is my code but its giving exception.

```
 System.Xml.Linq.XDocument feeddata = 
   System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(
    "http://feeds2.feedburner.com/plasticsnews/plasticsinformation/plastopedia");
  var maxPubDates = (from feeds in feeddata.Descendants("Feeds")select feeds );
  DateTime maxDate = maxPubDates.Max(feed => (DateTime) feed.Element("pubDate"));
```

Comment: What's the exception? Doing a direct cast to a (DateTime) is often dangerous, as the format of the date / time may not be what .NET is expecting.

Comment: exception in last line Sequence contains no elements..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the line:

```
var maxPubDates = (from feeds in feeddata.Descendants("Feeds") select feeds);
```

is not returning anything, as there is no descendant with tag "Feeds".

Change it to this line and you will get right results:

```
var maxPubDates = (from item in feeddata.Descendants("item") select item);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 feeddata.Descendants("item")
```

instead of

```
 feeddata.Descendants("Feeds")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing mainly because the uri doesn't contain any `<Feeds>` elements...?

Try:

```
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument feeddata = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(
    "http://feeds2.feedburner.com/plasticsnews/plasticsinformation/plastopedia");
var maxPubDates = feeddata.Descendants("item").Select(
        item => (DateTime)item.Element("pubDate")).Max();
```